# Difference between a mist pass and a normalized z-buffer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-passes

In Cycles there are two different render passes which seem to give some kind of depth information: the *Mist* pass and the *Z-Buffer* pass.  I know that the z-buffer gives the actual distance (thus producing values >1) while the mist pass's range is `[0,1]`.  But even after normalizing the z-buffer pass the two are still not the same, the mist pass is darker.

Here is a comparison (starting with the standard render).

[image]
[image]
[image]

So what is the mathematical difference between a mist pass and a normalized z-buffer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some differences:

- The *Mist* pass is antialiased. The *Z* pass is not.
- The [range](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/cycles/world_settings.html#mist-pass) for the mist pass is set independently of the camera's clip point.

  [image]
  [image]

  (To visualize the mist pass select the camera and enable mist on the Viewport display settings)

  [image]

  ***Start*** sets the black (0) portions of the image. ***Depth*** sets the range in which the mist pass will convert the distance to a grayscale. Past that range everyting is white (1).

  [image]
- The falloff on the mist pass can be changed to *quadratic*, *linear* or *Inverse Quadratic*. **The Z pass is always** ***linear***.

---

**Comparison**

If you set the clip distance and a mist pass to the same range and set the falloff to linear, the only difference is the antialiasing.

[image]

Comment: Where are the settings for the mist pass?

Comment: In the world settings, they are available once you enable the mist pass in the render layers.