# How do I do a Z Depth Pass?

Tags: render-passes

Wondering how I do a proper z depth pass. How do I get the hotel to show as well as the road? It's like it's getting cut off or something.[image]

[image]

Comment: the Z pass is available on the **Depth** socket of the render layer.  You will not be able to visualize the values over 1 unless you add a normalize node. Read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43638/difference-between-a-mist-pass-and-a-normalized-z-buffer/43641#43641 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88768/what-is-the-function-of-this-normalize/88769#88769 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52328/render-depth-maps-with-world-space-z-distance-with-respect-the-camera/52348#52348

Comment: If you want a 0-1 range between defined planes, a Mist pass can get that for you